# Get all amazon EC2 instance properties in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, attributes

I want to get for each instance family and type on AWS their properties and tags. For example how many cores, RAM, bandwidth etc is available at each instance that AWS provides e.g. x2.2xlarge, t1.micro etc. Is there any way I can do this with python?

The closest I have got is to use boto3 like this:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance('id')  #how to change this, brute force?
```

Any help regarding this problem will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think that this information is available as an API call. Instead, grab it from third-party websites like: https://www.ec2instances.info/

Comment: that's perfect, it allows to download csv file as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print all the attributes of a given instance, you can perform a describe call with a filter for that particular instance. Please note this is a 'client' call, not a 'resource' one. Meaning, you will get a JSON output, not an object. It is quite good to get to know all the attributes of an instance.

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

instance_id = 'i-xxxxxxxxx'
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
pprint(ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-id', 'Values': [instance_id]}]))
```

The documentation has all the properties listed, including the methods, collections, etc.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for instance id & instance state. you can add more parameters into it.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    print (instance.id , instance.state)
```